can fibers be replaced with coroutines in this simulator
I looking at a possibility of replacing an old simulator code that is using fibers (stackful) with C++ coroutines (stackless). I don't think it can be done without breaking other dependencies, but would like to keep the mechanism as much as possible. The fiber class looks like this:
struct fiber{
    fiber(const fiber&) = delete;
    fiber(scheduler& scheduler, std::function<void()> call_back, size_t stack_size = 4096);
    ~fiber();
    void suspend();
    void resume();
    void finish();
    void execute();
    void wait(event&);
    void wait(sim_time_t = 0);
    static auto get_current() -> fiber*;
private:
    scheduler& _scheduler;
    std::function<void()> _call_back;
    bool _finished{false};
    void* _win_fiber;
};

The key functions here that need replacement are these:
fiber* fiber::get_current() { return (fiber*)GetFiberData(); }

void fiber::suspend() {   // call from this fiber
    ::SwitchToFiber(_scheduler._main_fiber);
}

void fiber::resume() {   // call from main fiber
    ::SwitchToFiber(_win_fiber);
}

Basically, get_current() determines which fiber current code is running on, suspend() always yields to the scheduler, and resume() returns to the suspended fiber. A simplified demo is here.
C++ coroutines work quite differently, and I'm looking at the least invasive way of modifying code while keeping the other classes intact. Suggestions?

did you look into boost::cobalt ? most importantly it implements the cobalt::promise, which is what is needed for coroutines continuation.

@Ahmed AEK - I'm familiar with typical use of coroutines, it's this particular case that causes problems. Coroutines when suspended return to the caller, this code needs the return to the scheduler, which is several stack frames away. Also coroutines are suspended from its body, but this needs to be suspended from several function calls from the body.

The more I think about it the more I'm inclined to think it's not possible. I think it's the nature of C++ coroutines being stackless that prevents from having suspension/resumption points being several stacks away from coroutine.

you are right, you cannot implement stackful coroutines using stackless coroutines, but your code can still be written to work using stackless coroutines, the event object is basically cobat::channel, and your "scheduler" is basically a cobalt "executor", you just need to write one that checks coroutines according to priorities, the act of calling a function would be simply co_wait a function that returns a cobalt::promise ... all functions that can be suspended should return a cobalt::promise so that you can do symmetric transfer to them, and only 1 coroutine is in the stack

@Ahmed AEK - yes, it's possible, I have a simulator skeleton with coroutines, but it breaks all existing code, it will require a complete rewrite including all existing derivative works. It also makes usage of the library more awkward.
